# Stop tasks when navigating away from pivot item

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a pivot app where all the pivot items are web dependent.These pivot items update themselves when user navigates to them.So is there any way I can stop whatever the current pivot item is doing(be it web access,updating database) so that my app doesn't lag and the reaction time is quick? Currently it hangs a bit if the current pivot item is getting updated(async web retrieval of images etc).
I want the effect just like the "People" hub.

Comment: Please provide a code sample, specifically showing how you are currently connecting the web data to the controls on the PivotPage.  Then we'll be in a better position to suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

if you choose to stop the activities of current pivot,it will also take same time and the problem will still exist.i would suggest you to put loader with timer(1 second) for each pivot item.When you will move to next pivotitem,first start the timer(dont start any other activity) and when that timer expires,start other activities in timerTick. So the user experience will be good and It will not give the zigzag experience,